# jQuery checkbox change event to expand collapsible through another checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please refer : https://jsfiddle.net/3msLwfu6/1/
Tab 1 is a collapsible which contains "Items" which are nested collapsibles.
Each "Item" collapse state is controlled by a checkbox on the item header using bootstrap controls.
Tab 1 also controls a "Select All" checkbox which selects checkboxes of all "Items" using JS.

```
<div class="collapse-accordion" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="heading-1">
    <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a class="d-block" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-1">
        Tab 1
        <span class="float-right">Select All <input type="checkbox" id="sa_foo" name="sa_foo" data-checkbox-name="foo" class="selectall"/></span>
        </a>
    </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse-1" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-1">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div id="accordion-1">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header" id="heading-1-1">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                        <a class="collapsed">
                        Item 1
                        </a>
                        <span class="float-right"><input type="checkbox" id="foo_1" name="foo" value="1" data-select-all="sa_foo" class="checkme" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-1-1"/></span>
                    </h5>
                    </div>
                        <div id="collapse-1-1" name="foo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading-1-1">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            Text 1
                        </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>      
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// Select All checkbox should not expand accordion header
$(".selectall").on("click", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
    // Select all Items once Select All checkbox is clicked
$(':checkbox.selectall').on('click', function(){
  $(':checkbox[name="' + $(this).data('checkbox-name') + '"]').prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

});

With this setup, I expected the "Select All" checkbox to also control the show/hide of nested "Items" but that's not the case.
What am I missing?

Comment: Tab 1 and Select All are inside the same <a> tag so do the same thing. Select All would want its own <a> tag and event handler.

Comment: That is to align Tab 1 and Select All. To prevent Select All from expanding the header, I added event.stopPropagation().

Comment: Placing your Select All inside that anchor is not a good solution.  
Stopping the propagation is a bad fix caused by that bad solution.  
The Tab 1 anchor is decorated when Select All is hovered.

Comment: @Gh0sT I would do the design alignment with a div or something and let them have their own <a> and event handler, I still think that's where the prob is..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5L9p4kos/

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention. I also need the entire accordion header to be clickable no just on the text.

Comment: You should be able to come up with a nice solution by combining things from the 3 fiddles by Matthew Page, sking and me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look with an inspection tool what is happening there.
The Item 1 checkbox reacts to being clicked and a bunch of changes are made.

[image]

Here is an ugly workarround that should get you going.
[ugly but working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p2f36mhu/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Select All checkbox should not expand accordion header
    $(".selectall").on("click", function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
    // Select all Items once Select All checkbox is clicked
    $(':checkbox.selectall').on('click', function(){
        //$(':checkbox[name="' + $(this).data('checkbox-name') + '"]').prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
        $(':checkbox[name="' + $(this).data('checkbox-name') + '"]').click();
    });
});
```

Comment: This works. Why would you call it ugly?  
Also what would be a better approach in your view. Sorry I am very green to front end stuff.

Comment: As Matthew Page said keep it separated (look at his fiddle).  
My version is ugly because it is not separated and uses still the stop.propagation crutch.  
But it has a label for the checkbox ;)  
Learn to use an inspector and the console.  
Developer tools are a great help.

Comment: Alright..thank you very much. Just 1 last question.
If I qucikly double click on the nested "Items" checkbox, it's function is inverted..meaning check to collapse, uncheck to expand. How do I stop that?

Comment: That is a problem within that accordion code.  
The animated un-/collapsing process takes time and multiple clicks mess up the thing. The checkbox should be disabled during the animation. Way to complex to solve this here and now. The accordion code needs to be analyzed and modified. Perhaps the author of the accordion is willing to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

use `.click()` instead of `.prop`

demo here https://jsfiddle.net/8jmsten3/

Comment: @Gh0sT yes the animation is binded on `click` event. Please aceept the answer if it works for you :)